# How to generate "select count(*)as y from (select distinct x, y from tableName) as t" using NH?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Any ideas on how to generate the follow query with Nhibernate using the Criteria API?

```
select count(*)as z from (select distinct x, y from tableName) as t
```

or

```
select count(distinct (x , y)) as z FROM tableName
```

or

some other query that returns the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to generate such a query with the help of ICriteria API and Projection. What you are going to need are `Projections.RowCount()`, `Projections.Distinct()`, `Projections.Property()`

Comment: Could you write that query down ... cause the syntax and ordering is critical ... thanks

Comment: If you have the proper query please list it down, because I'm having the same problem and struggling to make it work!
Thanks